# rains hard enough to cause all the damage

Tags: meaning

I have the text:

> She drove slowly on the narrow road. Her car dipped and rocked through washed-out  sections, though I couldn't remember **rains hard enough to cause all the damage**.

I can't understand fully what the text in bold is meaning, because of ambiguity of sense in my brains. Can you tell me which is correct?

1) rains were hard enough to cause all the damage.

2) any hard enough rains causing all the damage.

Comment: It is rather oddly expressed. The narrator couldn't remember any recent rainstorms hard enough to cause such damage to the road.

Comment: It's a relative clause reduced by _Whiz_-deletion: _I couldn't remember rains **which were** hard enough to cause all the damage_.

Comment: I think this question belongs on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). But I would just say that stereotypically we Brits speak of little else *apart* from the weather, so my opinion on "idiomacy" here should count for *something*. And in the cited context, I'd always expect singular ***rain*** (to me, plural ***rains*** implies a reference to the monsoon season in the Far East, which I think isn't relevant to the US-based narrative context here).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I've seen ***rains*** (plural) used in AmE to indicate multiple instances - semantically, it would be equivalent to ***rainstorms*** - "...I couldn't remember rain[storm]s hard enough to cause all the damage."

Comment: @FF I'm not unhappy with the plural usage here; it's literary, and is fine to my mind for 'bouts of rain'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Well, we Brits were taught by GBS *(Pygmalion)* that if we wanted to sound posh, we had to say *The **rain** in Spain stays mainly in the plain*, not the ***rains***. But suppose we switched from ***rains*** to ***storms*** in the cited context. Don't you think singular *...can't remember [any] **storm**...* would work better with that?

Comment: @FF Perhaps, but from [The Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/1404051/Are-those-hazy-days-of-summer-just-a-memory.html): 'Days of torrential rain eased yesterday as the once-in-a-decade storm that ravaged much of Britain last week finally blew over.

However, the respite will be brief. The Met Office warned that the rains were set to return, though with less intensity, over the next few days to fuel fears that this will be one of the wettest summers on record.' Oh, by Matt Born, 10 Aug 2002. It seems like only yesterday.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Doesn’t that amount to saying that the plural is unconventional rather than idiosyncratic?

Comment: @Tuffy - I wouldn't even say that it's unconventional; without actually doing a Google NGram search, I'd say anecdotally that neither usage is particularly marked.

Answer (score 1):

> though I couldn't remember rains hard enough to cause all the damage.

"Rains" here is not a verb but rather a noun.  A "rain" is a noticeable event of precipitation.  So the writer could not remember events of rainfall that were severe enough to wash out places in the road (which was presumably constructed of gravel or dirt).

I've seen some rains here in southern Minnesota this summer which severely rutted gravel driveways (and probably some rural gravel roads).